# Java Generics: compatible service subclass

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I need a service lookup method that returns a compatible service. These particular services are (non-generic) subclasses of the same generic superclass, and I'd like to use generics to assure compatibility.

Classes:

- `class BaseDTO`
- `class AaaDTO extends BaseDTO`
- `class BbbDTO extends BaseDTO`
- `interface BaseService<T extends BaseDTO>`
- `interface AaaService extends BaseService<AaaDTO>`
- `interface BbbService extends BaseService<BbbDTO>`

What generics definitions must I put into the placeholders in the resolver class below? I want to express that `resolve()` returns a service implementation that is compatible to the given object.

```
public class Resolver {
    @Autowired private AaaService aaaService;
    @Autowired private BbbService bbbService;

    public <T ???> BaseService<???> resolve(T object) {
        if (object instanceof AaaDTO) {
            return (???) aaaService;
        } else if (object instanceof BbbDTO) {
            return (???) bbbService;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```

Simply said I want to tell the compiler that the following is safe:

```
BaseDTO dto = getDtoFromSomewhereElse();
resolver.resolve(dto).foo(dto);
```

Comment: Have you tried <T extends BaseDTO>? For this to work, resolver.resolve(X).foo(Y) must have X and Y as superclasses of BaseDTO though.

Comment: Yes, that is the obvious choice for the method's generic. I cannot guarantee `BaseService<T>`, as `T` could theoretically be a subclass of `AaaDTO`, so I returned `BaseService<? super T>`. That apparently was the problem, I changed that to `BaseService<T>` which the compiler accepts. Still warnings about the cases, though. The method of course only makes sense when `object` is a subclass of `BaseDTO`, otherwise there is no service anyway. The idea of the resolver is `X == Y` by the way: find and invoke the appropriate service implementation for a given object.

Comment: If T is a subclass of AaaDTO, then it is also a subclass of BaseDTO since inheritance is transitive, i.e. if (A inherits from B) and (B inherits from C) then (A inherits from C). Does your code work after the change or is it still having problems?

Comment: It works fine now. But inheritance and generics don't go that easy together. There are several questions on SO regarding why `List<Animal> l = new ArrayList<Dog>` doesn't work. (Short: you could add a Cat to `List<Animal>` but not to `List<Dog>`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method foo is defined in `BaseService`as follows:

```
public void foo(BaseDTO dto);
```

You could do the following:

```
 public <T extends BaseDTO> BaseService<T> resolve(T object) {
        if (object instanceof AaaDTO) {
            return (BaseService<T>) aaaService;
        } else if (object instanceof BbbDTO) {
            return (BaseService<T>) bbbService;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: That simple... Theoretically `T` could be a subclass of `AaaDTO` and still only `AaaService` is returned. So I had tried to return `BaseService<? super T>`, which apparently was my problem.